# Automated download of website content using ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, parsing, screen-scraping

Using ASP.net, what methods can I use to do the following:

1. Open up a connection to a given URL to read HTML content
2. Parse the given URL for hyperlinks, and place them in an array
3. Loop through each hyperlink (only 1 level down), opening each one, saving the HTML contents in a table, and move to the next hyperlink until done.

If ASP.net is not up to the task, other languages or free scripts/toolkits would be acceptable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use a [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144200.aspx) for step 1.
- Use System.Text.RegularExpressions as shown [here](http://damieng.com/blog/2006/07/07/url_parsing_and_manipulation_in_net) for step 2.
- Create and use a [System.Data.DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6zd7cwzh.aspx) for step 2.
- See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w.aspx) for step 3

I left out the obvious things, such as "loop through the DataTable", etc.  A more in-depth answer is probably not something that will be coming from this site.  The question is a bit too big to answer completely here.

Comment: Sounds good - just a couple of follow-up questions: 1. Does System.Net.WebClient work like a file stream? Any links for a good tutorial, perhaps? 2. Am I right to assuming that the simulated "click" on a hyperlink in the loop is basically to point a WebClient variable to the URL for that array item? I'm new at this, so bear with me - thanks.

Comment: 1. yes I believe the method is DownloadFile(), but off the top of my head I'm not sure.  Check the documentaiton in the "Methods" section.

 2. yes.